# Flutter web-app: How to extract JWT from response

Tags: flutter, jwt

Maybe this question makes no sense. But let me ask anyway.

I have a Flutter web-app (not mobile) and a Rails back-end. I'm using `devise-jwt` on the Rails end to authenticate and send back a JWT on sign-in.

So far, so good. I can see the JWT in the response

[image]

Problem is, when I try to extract the JWT, as follows ...

```
    postRequest(url, form).then((response) {
       print(response.headers.keys); 
    }) ;
```

... I find that `Authorization` is not visible in `response.headers.keys`.

Maybe this (not exposing `Authorization`) is a security feature specific to web-apps. Or, I'm missing something really small.

Hence, I'm wondering if:

1. accessing the JWT is even possible in a Flutter web-app?
2. if yes, then how?
3. if no, then is the only option to send back an `httpOnly` cookie?
4. can the `Authorization` header be accessed only in mobile apps?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found out how `Authorization` can be made visible (by Rails) before it can be accessed at the Flutter end.

In `config/initializers/cors.rb`, expose `Authorization` header as shown

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins 'http://localhost:8080'
    resource '*', \
    headers: :any, \
    expose: ['Authorization'],\
    methods: [:get, :post]
  end 
end
```

This still leaves open the question of how best to store JWT on the browser - now that it can be accessed. And it seems `httpOnly` cookies are the way to go